# DatePicker form material-ui-redux-form + Redux Form - enable text input

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I am using DatePicker as a component to my Field from redux form. Right now each time I focus on the field the date picker opens. I cannot write the date to the input from the keyboadrd on my own (or paste it). I would like to combine both - enable user to paste/input the date from keyboard or pick it from date picker... How can I achieve this ?

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { DatePicker } from 'redux-form-material-ui';
```

....

```
<Field
  name="dateOfBirth"
  type="text"
  component={DatePicker}
  fullWidth
  formatDate={formatDate}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a field in your component's "state".
2. Insert `value` attribute to your `<Field>`, equal to the value of the state field. Also set the value of your DatePicker equal to this state field.
3. In `onChange` of your `<Field>` and in `onChange` of your DatePicker, call `setState` to update the value of that state field.
4. Now `DatePicker` and `<Field>` both will see the state change and update the value inside them.

Search for "React controlled input" for more details. [Here](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/cc70c575d41b30c5b3bcc242dc8f7cca) is an example.

**Update 1**

I have not tested the following code. You might have to make changes to convert string to `moment` and vice-versa. `DatePicker` tag will also change based on which DatePicker library you are using. But this *pseudo* code should give you an idea on how to approach the problem.

Basically I have a `DatePicker` and an `input`, both of which show the `dob` from the component's state. And when their values are changed, the `onSomethingChange` functions will update the state value, hence updating both the `DatePicker` and the `input`. Hope this helps.

```
this.state = {
  dob: moment(props.dob)
};

<DatePicker
    date={this.state.dob}
    onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
    ... other attributes
/>

<input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.dob}
    onChange={this.onInputDateChange}
    ... other attributes
/>

onDateChange = (dob) => {
    if (dob) {
      this.setState(() => ({ dob }));
    }
};

onInputDateChange = (e) => {
    const dob = e.target.value;
    if (dob) {
      this.setState(() => ({ dob }));
    }
};
```

Comment: Same question for me here, but this does not seem to work. This is a general approach with controlled inputs and redux-form but in the case of date picker the input does not seem to allow typing. Have you tried this approach in a codesandbox that I can take a look at ? btw I am using react-datepicker which might work differently

Comment: can you post your updated code so we can figure out what it is that you missed?

Comment: I set this state as you told to do, followed the example but the issue is each time I click on input DatePicker opens so I have no chance to enter text on my own anyway